# SQL is not connected in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, linux, xampp, ubuntu-18.04

My Sql is not able to connect with the xampp server. There is no **password** in my sql and also i have missing ***mysql.sock*** and run folder is empty.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6LYE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow https://vitux.com/how-to-install-xampp-on-your-ubuntu-18-04-lts-system/.

If problem persists then try ubuntu forums I guess.